# In the C++, does template instantiated when I specialized it?

Tags: c++, templates

I know the template can't occupy memory in the run-time if I can't specialized it.

For example:

```
//code 1
template<typename T>
class foo {
  T val;
}
```

If typename is int, only generate following code:

```
//code 2
template<typename T>
class foo {
  int val;
}
```

The code 1 cannot be generate, so code cannot occupy memory in the run-time .

Now I specialized code 1

```
//code 3
template<>
class foo<double> {
  double val;
}
```

Does code 3 occupy memory in the run-time?

Comment: Template are generated when the compiler detect an instantiation of an object of a given type, not when you declare a specialization.. 

You can declare as much specialization as you want, only the ones you instantiate will generate code to be executed at run-time.

Comment: It's implementation defined.

Comment: So If I can't invoke code 3 in my main function, can't code 3 occupy memory? I assume above code implement in others files(impl.h and impl.cc), not be included in main.cc

Comment: For clang and gcc, template not invoked is not compiled (i.e. it does not generate any code).

Comment: If you are building library, the machine code for the specialization is probably wanted in the library build, but then the linker in ideal case should not put that into the final executable, if such specialization is not invoked. One way to be sure what your toolchain is actually doing, is to use linking step "map" to see which parts of code went into the binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check such questions with https://godbolt.org/:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
  foo(T v) : val(v) {}
  T val;
};

template<>
struct foo<int> {
  foo(int v) : val(v) {}
  int val;
};

template<>
struct foo<double> {
  foo(double v) : val(v) {}
  double val;
};

int main() {
    foo<int> a(5);
    foo<short> b(10);
    return a.val + b.val;
}
```

This code was compiled with clang (trunk) -O0. The output is

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 8]
        mov     esi, 5
        call    foo<int>::foo(int)
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 16]
        mov     esi, 10
        call    foo<short>::foo(short)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
        movsx   ecx, word ptr [rbp - 16]
        add     eax, ecx
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
foo<int>::foo(int):                         # @foo<int>::foo(int)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 12], esi
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 12]
        mov     dword ptr [rax], ecx
        pop     rbp
        ret
foo<short>::foo(short):                         # @foo<short>::foo(short)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 8], rdi
        mov     word ptr [rbp - 10], si
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rbp - 8]
        mov     cx, word ptr [rbp - 10]
        mov     word ptr [rax], cx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

As you can see only the methods that are actually used are created.

Comment: Thanks your instance!